# Need CSS styles for default input/submit button

Tags: css, html

Can someone advice CSS styles for default input/submit button please?
I need to mimic a default input/submit button with css. 
The default button is the one, which browser creates once you specify input type="button" in your HTML.
I need to use the button that would look like default input/submit button inside href, but using button inside href is not legal in HTML5.
So I want to do the following:

```
<a href="#"><span class="button">Input button</span></a>
```

Just need css for my class .button that would create the button that looks like default input/submit button.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: "Looks like the default" in which browser? Different browsers style the default button differently. And by "input/submit button" do you mean `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: Not to mention different operating systems.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will work for you

```css
.button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.16, rgb(207, 207, 207)), color-stop(0.79, rgb(252, 252, 252)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(207, 207, 207) 16%, rgb(252, 252, 252) 79%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(207, 207, 207) 16%, rgb(252, 252, 252) 79%); 
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="somlink.html">button</a>
```

you need to select proper background-image as different browser renders in different manner

**Edit:**  added `background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(207, 207, 207) 16%, rgb(252, 252, 252) 79%);`  for IE10 and above

Comment: Thank you Manoj!
This is by far the best css I got.
Firefox and Chrome display this code identical to other default buttons that I have on page.
IE, as usual, does not render background-image at all.
Is there any conditional or additional css that I could use for IE?

Comment: @Sloger ,  yes you can use -ms-linear-gradient is supported in IE 10 please refer this link to use for previous version,[link] https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients

Comment: I am adding:
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient (
       center bottom, 
       rgb(207,207,207) 16%,
       rgb(252,252,252) 79%);
for IE but it does nothing. Is this a correct code?

Comment: please use <code> background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(207,207,207) 16%, rgb(252,252,252) 79%);</code>

Comment: Thank you, it worked. With minor tweaking I managed it to look very similar to default submit buttons. I changed "border-radius" to 2px, and border:1px solid #777777;

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is;

1. Create a default button with html
2. Make the button a link that will redirect to another page when clicked with the `<a href=#>` element.

These are my thoughts;

1. You need to use either the `<button>` element placed inside the `<a>` element. The `<button>` element will create a default button without any css.
2. You can use `<input>` element with the type attribute set to submit. Place it inside the `<a>` element and you will have your default button that links to wherever you want.

Below is the code to show examples. I hope it solves your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="http://www.google.com"><button>Submit</button></a>

<a href="http://www.google.com"><input type="Submit" value="Submit"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't nest interactive elements. The OP's problem is that nesting like that is illegal, and you're just replacing some illegal markup with some other illegal markup. Not a solution at all.

Answer (score -2):

Use bootstrap...
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/, find templates here https://bootswatch.com/cosmo/

You could, as well, use semantic-ui.com.

I hope I helped you :D